# UAC installation questions

Tags: windows, uac

would like to check, if a domain account does not have admin rights they would be prompt for password when doing installation.

if the UAC is turned off on that Account, would they be able to install things on their own accord?

Comment: What problem are you truly trying to solve?

Comment: we setup the PC to be locked by local admin account, which means no one able to install stuffs without us typing in the password.
however, there was one PC that installed programs, updated teamviewer to latest version without us typing in the password. 
after the check i found out that the UAC was turned off.. could that be the reason why he is able to install even without admin rights?

Comment: UAC cannot easily be turned off.  It requires multiple group policies to be configured.  Simply setting the UAC notification level to its lowest setting does not disable UAC.